# ¿Cómo extraigo la información recibida de requests.get()?

Tags: python, json

Estoy haciendo una integracion con una API, el problema es que no sé cómo extraer la información que quiero del array que me devuelve. Tampoco lo puedo pasar a string...

El código es:

```
list1 = []
url = 'https://zzz/segmentation?client_key=xxx&model_id=yyy&image_url=xy'
response = requests.get(url)
json_response = response.json()
```

Cuando hago `print json_response` recibo:

```
{"response": {"objects": [["x", 442, 10, 845, 343], ["y", 1162, 162, 1378, 284], ["t", 142, 151, 465, 747], ["z", 594, 436, 729, 686], ["l", 1142, 455, 1369, 692], ["m", 26, 613, 1338, 794]]}, "error": "false"}
```

Lo que no se es como extraer ahora los valores objects pertinentes.¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Hola Xavi y bienvenido a [es.so]. ¿Podrías [edit] la publicación indicando el resultado de `requests.get(url)`? Entiendo que es un JSON y que quieres procesarlo, pero iría bien verlo. ¿Qué te devuelve si dices `print(response.content)`?

Comment: Con `print (response.content)` me devuelve:

`{"response": {"objects": [["x", 442, 10, 845, 343], ["y", 1162, 162, 1378, 284], ["t", 142, 151, 465, 747], ["z", 594, 436, 729, 686], ["l", 1142, 455, 1369, 692], ["m", 26, 613, 1338, 794]]}, "error": "false"}`
 
Lo que no se es como extraer ahora los valores objects pertinentes

Comment: Discúlpame. Ya lo he añadido.

Comment: Pues por lo que parece ya tienes el JSON. Si escribes por ejemplo `print json_response['response']['objects']` debería devolverte cosas como `[['x', 442, 10, 845, 343], ['y', 1162, 162, 1378, 284], ['t', 142, 151, 465, 747], ['z', 594, 436, 729, 686], ['l', 1142, 455, 1369, 692], ['m', 26, 613, 1338, 794]]`. ¿Es así?

Comment: Si, en efecto. Por último, podrias decirme como podría extraer `json_response['response']['objects'] donde ['objects'] = 'x'` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por lo que indicas en tu actualización:

> ```
> response = requests.get(url)
> json_response = response.json()
> ```
>
> Cuando hago print json_response recibo:
>
> ```
> {"response": {"objects": [["x", 442, 10, 845, 343], ["y", 1162, 162, 1378, 284], ["t", 142, 151, 465, 747], ["z", 594, 436, 729, 686], ["l", 1142, 455, 1369, 692], ["m", 26, 613, 1338, 794]]}, "error": "false"}
> ```

Por tanto, ya estás recibiendo un diccionario y solamente debes trabajar con él normalmente y recibirás los siguientes valores, por ejemplo:

```
>>> print(json_response['response']['objects'])
[['x', 442, 10, 845, 343], ['y', 1162, 162, 1378, 284], ['t', 142, 151, 465, 747], ['z', 594, 436, 729, 686], ['l', 1142, 455, 1369, 692], ['m', 26, 613, 1338, 794]]
```

> Si, en efecto. Por ultimo, podrias decirme como podría extraer `json_response['response']['objects']` donde `['objects'] = 'x'`

Lo que quieres es extraer la lista cuyo primer elemento es `x`, dentro de `json_response['response']['objects']`.

Para empezar tenemos:

```
>>> print(json_response['response']['objects'])
[['x', 442, 10, 845, 343], ['y', 1162, 162, 1378, 284], ['t', 142, 151, 465, 747], ['z', 594, 436, 729, 686], ['l', 1142, 455, 1369, 692], ['m', 26, 613, 1338, 794]]
```

Lo que podemos hacer es una comprensión de listas en la que elegimos aquella lista cuyo primer elemento es 'x':

```
>>> [el for el in json_response['response']['objects'] if el[0]=='x']
[['x', 442, 10, 845, 343]]
```

Si te fijas, y como es normal, esto retorna una lista de listas que cumplen la condición. Si solo quieres la primera, añade un `[0]`:

```
>>> [el for el in json_response['response']['objects'] if el[0]=='x'][0]
['x', 442, 10, 845, 343]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, muy amable.

Comment: @Xavi faltaría más, un placer. Como eres nuevo aquí puede serte útil consultar [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](/help/someone-answers). ¡Nos vemos en el sitio!

Answer (score 1):

La librería `requests` cuenta con un decodificar de JSON en caso de que estés trabajando con datos JSON. En tu caso en particular solamente tendrías que acceder a cada una de las claves del diccionario.

```
list1 = []
url = 'https://zzz/segmentation?client_key=xxx&model_id=yyy&image_url=xy'
response = requests.get(url)

# Decodifica la respuesta del servidor y devuelve un objeto nativo de Python
json_response = response.json()

/*
Valor de json_response:

{
    "response":{
        "objects":[
            ["x",442,10,845,343],
            ["y",1162,162,1378,284],
            ["t",142,151,465,747],
            ["z",594,436,729,686],
            ["l",1142,455,1369,692],
            ["m",26,613,1338,794]]
    },
    "error":"false"
}
*/

print(json_response["response"]["objects"])
# [["x", ..], ["y", ..], ["t", ..], ["z", ..], ["l", ..], ["m", ..]]

print(json_response["response"]["objects"][0])
# ["x",442,10,845,343]

print(json_response["error"])
# false"
```

---

¿No estás usando la librería `request`? No importa, porque Python cuenta con el paquete `json` que permite la codificación y decodificación de archivos.

**Codificar JSON** (De un tipo nativo de Python a un JSON)

```
import json

data = {'clave' : 'valor'}
json.dumps(data)
```

**Decodicar JSON** (De JSON a un tipo nativo de Python)

```
import json

data = '{"clave" : "valor"}'
json.loads(data)
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Al cambiar la ultima linea de código me devuelve un error:

  line 12, in <module>
    json_response = json.loads(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
TypeError: expected string or buffer

Comment: ¡Muy buena respuesta, Matias! Útil para el autor de la pregutna y para quien venga en el futuro.

Answer (score 0):

Buen dia compañeros, deseaba efectuar una consulta sobre como extraer la información de la respuesta a la invocación de un API con el comando GET.

la respuesta es:

{
"custom": {
"PRECIO_CONTADO_OF": "2,248.64",
"PRECIO_CONTADO": "2,366.99",
"CUOTA12_OF": "201.96",
"CUOTA06_OF": "389.35",
"CUOTA12": "212.59",
"CUOTA09_OF": "266.51",
"GARANTIA": "",
"PVP": "2,629.99",
"LEYENDA_3": "Extension de Garantia Original por 2 años:",
"DESCUENTO": "10% DE DESCUENTO",
"VALOR06_OF": "2,336.09",
"VALOR12": "2,551.09",
"VALOR09_OF": "2,398.55",
"CUOTA18_OF": "138.81",
"VALOR12_OF": "2,423.54",
"LEYENDA": "PVP incluye IVA. Las ventas a plazos se calculan del PVP. Aplican planes y condiciones de financiamiento vigentes. Plazos exclusivos para socios SUKASA",
"VALOR09": "2,524.79",
"VIGENCIA": "DEL:28-ABR-2022 AL:23-MAY-2022",
"LEYENDA2": "*Promocion: 5% de dcto. El descuento adicional, por forma de pago, se activa según el plazo. ",
"CUOTA18": "146.11",
"CUOTA06": "409.84",
"VALOR06": "2,459,04",
"CUOTA09": "280.53"
},
"description": "LS66MXN",
"storeId": "retailpoint_ec.lab",
"creationDate": "2022-07-21T14:55:37.125Z",
"extended": null,
"matching": {
"count": 1,
"matched": true,
"labels": [
"D309CC02"
]
},
"itemId": "2852910",
"multimedia": {
"nfc": "",
"url": "www.eluniverso.com"
},
"modificationDate": "2022-08-30T22:14:33.979Z",
"deletionDate": null,
"name": "REFRIGERADOR S/S 612LTS SILVER INSTAN T VIEW DIGITAL INVERTER",
"id": "2852910",
"brand": "LG ELECT -E-",
"status": "ACTIVE",
"_score": 1
}

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: El codigo es el siguiente:


import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api-us.vusion.io")
payload = ''
headers = {
  'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '4e3cee7baa584539b24805927cc7f492'
}
conn.request("GET", "/vcloud/v1/stores/retailpoint_ec.lab/items/2852910", payload, headers)
res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()

print(data.decode("utf-8"))

Comment: Esta es la seccion de respuestas, si necesitas preguntar algo debes formular una nueva pregunta. Esto no es una respuesta a la pregunta,  formula una pregunta bien detallada, lee [ask].

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/354638)